# SharePoint Online Version Column Formatting via JSON

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, json, modern-experience, json-formatting

I am trying to archive the following within a document library modern experience on SharePoint Online:

- All minor version (everything .1-9) the background should have the color red or similar
- All Major versions (1.0, 2.0, 3.0 etc.) should have the background color green or similar.

It **needs to be done via JSON** and via the "format this column" in SharePoint Online.

Is there a way to create an "IF-Clause" checking only the last digit? If yes, I could easily identify, due to the fact, that all major version are a "0" at the end. Maybe something like *RIGHT[@currentField]*? If so, how do I implement that into an IF-Clause?

Current state of my pretty poor JSON:

```
{
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "div",
   "attributes": {
     "class": "=if(@currentField <= '0.9','sp-field-severity--warning', '')"
   },
   "children": [
     {
       "elmType": "span",
       "style": {
         "display": "inline-block",
         "padding": "0 4px"
       },
       "attributes": {
         "iconName": "=if(@currentField <= '0.9','Error', '')"
       }
     },
     {
       "elmType": "span",
       "txtContent": "@currentField"
     }
   ]
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the JSON formatting below to achieve it.

```
{
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "div",
   "style": {
    "background-color": "=if(indexOf(@currentField, '.0')!=-1, 'green', 'red')",
    "color":"white" 
   },
   "children": [
     {
       "elmType": "span",
       "style": {
            "margin-top":"11px"
       },
       "txtContent": "@currentField"
     }
   ]
 }
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm glad to be back here in this community. I know, why I asked my question in this forum! Could you maybe also write a sentence or two, what how it actually works and what the IF-Clause means?

Comment: I suggest you read the official document: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting

Answer (score 1):

slightly updated version making use of the supported CSS styles:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "attributes": {
    "class": "=if(indexOf(@currentField, '.0')!=-1,'sp-field-severity--good', 'sp-field-severity--warning')"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "txtContent": "=if(indexOf(@currentField, '.0')!=-1, '@currentField', @currentField + ' - Publish me!')"
    }
  ]
}
```